# array to linked list function in C; how to iterate over list to attach the node?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I am constructing some code that would basically take in an arrray, and return a linked list in the same order. I'm stuck in a conditional with no way out. How to attach the temp to node? I know I have to traverse by ->next till its not null but I can't figure out how.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct ListNode{

    int data;
    struct ListNode* next;

};

struct ListNode populateLinkedList(int arr[], int arraysize){
    struct ListNode* head = NULL;
    struct ListNode* lastNodePtr = NULL;
    struct ListNode* node = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++){

        struct ListNode* tempNodePtr = (struct ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempNodePtr->data = arr[i];
        tempNodePtr->next = NULL;

        //if header is empty assign new node to header
        if(head==NULL) {
            head = tempNodePtr;
        }
            //if the temp node is empty assign new node to temp node
        else if(node==NULL) {
            node = tempNodePtr;
        }
            //if both header and temp node are not empty, attach the temp to node. This is where I get an error.
        else {
            struct ListNode* temp = *node->next;
            while (temp!=NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = tempNodePtr;
            node->next = temp;

        }
    }

    //connect head with nodes after index 0
    head->next = node;
    return head
}

int main() {
    printf("Entering program 2\n");

    int array[] = {5,8,2,4,12,97,25,66};
    int arraysize = (int)( sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
    printf("mainSize: %d \n", arraysize);

    populateLinkedList(array, arraysize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function should retutn a *pointer*. It is defined to return a *node*, and in practice, it returns *nothing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't have to iterate over the list at all if you do it backwards:

```
struct ListNode* populateLinkedList(int arr[], int arraysize) {
    struct ListNode* head = NULL;
    for (int i = arraysize; i > 0; i--) {
        struct ListNode* tempNodePtr = (struct ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(*tempNodePtr));
        tempNodePtr->data = arr[i - 1];
        tempNodePtr->next = head;
        head = tempNodePtr;
    }
    return head;
}
```

As you can see this is a lot simpler because there are no checks since you always replace the `head` and there's no need to iterate over already inserted elements so it's also more efficient.

---

As for what's wrong with your solution:

```
struct ListNode* temp = *node->next;
//                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
// you definitely shouldn't dereferrence anything here

// This condition is wrong because when you exit the loop "temp" will be NULL
while (temp!=NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = tempNodePtr;
node->next = temp; // <-- this is definitely not needed
```

So your code should've been something like this:

```
struct ListNode* temp = node;
while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = tempNodePtr;
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the creative solution. Also, could you also pinpoint what went wrong in my code? It's probably around the time where I declare ListNode temp but I can't figure out how to fix it.